# wordpress plugin add_action init inside class not called

Tags: class, plugins

Within a plugin I am trying to set up a do_action inside a static class during activation.  Here is the base script ( parts left out in order to simplify the example ):

```
function activate_prof_dir() {
      require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-activator.php';
      Prof_Dir_Activator::activate();
      }
```

The `activate` method within Prof_Dir_Activator class executes.  BUT, in the `activate` method I have this:

```
 class Prof_Dir_Activator {.......etc
 public static function activate(){
 add_action( 'init', array( 'Prof_Dir_Activator', 'func'  ), 0 );
 public static function func(){
      echo `hit`;
 }
```

...just to see if `init` is calling my function.

The function does not get executed.

Why?